# Simple functor in C++, STL

Tags: c++, stl, functor

Right now i have learning STL (C++).

In the next code i have a vector with integer elements [0;110), and I want to count the number of vector elements is divisible by 25 without remainder.

After running the program i'll see next output: 

1

2

3

4

5

Counter: 0

Why 0?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class dividesby
{
int counter;    
public:

int getCounter(){return counter;}
dividesby():counter(0){}
void operator ()(int i)
{
    if(i%25==0)
    {
        counter++;
        std::cout<<"\n"<<counter<<"\n";
    }
}
};

void main()
{
using namespace std;
vector <int> v;
for(int i=0;i<110;i++)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}
dividesby D;
for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),D);
cout<<"Counter: "<<D.getCounter()<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `for_each` takes its last argument **by value**, not **by reference**.

Do this:

```
D = for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),D);
```